# How to get index in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a vector of character type which has all the list of names.

So I'm looping through each name and peforming some actions. This loop is not based on the index/length (and I want to keep it this way).

However, if I want to access the index value in the loop how do I get it.

Ex:

```
names <- c("name1", "name2")

for(name in names){

#do something
print(name)

#here how would I get the index number? like 1, 2 etc?

}
```

Comment: In the tidyverse world, check out `imap`. No time now for a full answer, if someone wants to write one up or link to an answer using `imap`, please go ahead.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do something like this, which is literally getting the i value.

```
names <- c("name1", "name2")
i<-0
for(name in names){
    i<-i+1
    print(i)

}
```

Or change the loop to use a numeric index

```
names <- c("name1", "name2")
for(i in 1:length(names)){
    print(i)

}
```

Or use the `which` function.

```
names <- c("name1", "name2")
for(name in names){

    print(which(name == names))

}
```

Comment: Would the `which` way still be suitable if there are non unique entries in the list?

Comment: Did you try it? I think you will find it works, if I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 15):

For variety:

```
names <- c("name1", "name2")
for(i in seq_along(names)){
    print(i)
}
```

`seq_along` is a fast primitive, and IMO slightly sweeter syntactic sugar.