# How to transfer the value of the iteration of a loop and use it within the loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am currently trying to run a script in RStudio where part of it involves removing punctuation from a string in a data frame. Thus far this has been a particularly time-consuming step, so I want to try and insert a few output messages to make sure it hasn't crashed and is still running.

My idea was to try and put another loop within the loop removing punctuation which would output a printed message of what percentage completion the step was at, but only when the percentage value was a whole number so-as not to print a million messages.

I attempted it with something like the below, but the big problem here is that I'm fairly sure I'm using the "i" variable incorrectly, so this won't ever work like I have it written. So I'm hoping for fixes or alternatives to what I have within the if loop.

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(eqtls)){

      eqtls$gene_id_new[i]=rem_punct(eqtls$gene_id[i])

      if((i/nrow(eqtls)*(100))%%1=0){

        completion = (i/nrow(eqtls))*100

        message(sprintf("Percent complete: %s\n", completion))
      }
    }
```

To further clarify: this is purely academic now as I'm switching to a different method of removing the punctuation.

Comment: It's not a single `=`, that is an assignment. For the comparison use double `==`.

Comment: You could use `txtProgressBar` or `pblapply` from package `pbapply`, that'd be less awkward and more efficient  than the `%%` gimmick, I suspect however that your `rem_punct` function can be vectorized and made really fast, you might want to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Like I say at the bottom, the whole `rem_punct` function is actually one that I've retired because it was overall too slow a method for parsing the file. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one output line:

#### Data

```
eqtls <- data.frame("var1" = rep(paste(LETTERS[1:26],".",LETTERS[26:1],sep = ""),500), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(eqtls)){
    eqtls$var1[i] <- gsub("\\.","",eqtls$var1[i])
    if((i/nrow(eqtls)*(100))%%1 == 0){
        cat(paste(round((i/nrow(eqtls))*100,0), "%..."))
    }
}
```

#### Result

```
> 1 %...2 %...3 %...4 %...5 %...6 %...8 %...9 %...10 %...11 %...12 %...
13 %...15 %...16 %...17 %...18 %...19 %...20 %...21 %...22 %...23 %...
24 %...25 %...26 %...27 %...30 %...31 %...32 %...33 %...34 %...35 %...
36 %...37 %...38 %...39 %...40 %...41 %...42 %...43 %...44 %...45 %...
46 %...47 %...48 %...49 %...50 %...51 %...52 %...53 %...54 %...59 %...
60 %...61 %...62 %...63 %...64 %...65 %...66 %...67 %...68 %...69 %...
70 %...71 %...72 %...73 %...74 %...75 %...76 %...77 %...78 %...79 %...
80 %...81 %...82 %...83 %...84 %...85 %...86 %...87 %...88 %...89 %...
90 %...91 %...92 %...93 %...94 %...95 %...96 %...97 %...98 %...99 %...
100 %...
```

Comment: That is more or less exactly what I was going for, thanks very much!

Comment: If you feel that this or any other post answers question it is really recommended that you click on the green checkmark so that the thread can be marked as "answered". [More info on how to choose a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

This link - [How to get index in a loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205370/how-to-get-index-in-a-loop-in-r][1]) should help you with loops in R.

In general - if you want to iterate over the value in a loop just do -

```
for(i in eqtls){
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice there! While I know your code would work however, I didn't want to do that because it would have printed literally millions of lines, and I was aiming for something more elegant.